# calling an x-api-key in the header of an Angular service

Tags: javascript, angular, api

I am trying to call an x-api-key in the header of an angular service but am missing something in the syntax. So far my code spits out an authorization error.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PrecipForecastService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getData () {
    const url = 'url_here';
    const key = 'key_here';
    const header = new HttpHeaders({'x-api-key': key});
    return this.http.get(url, {headers: header});
  }
}
```

The browser's network tab shows:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'url_here' from origin 'localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Yes the key is correct, it worked with the JS fetch module.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does your back-end accepts any case? E.g. maybe accepts only case sensitive `X-Api-Key`

Comment: Custom request header has to be first enabled on server (configuration level). Please check whether it has been exposed/enabled from server(it is case sensitive too).

Comment: The backend documentation specifies 'x-api-key'. I also tried multiple case types (X-Api-Key and X-API-KEY) with no success. Also yes the backend accepts this request as I have it working in vanilla JS with the fetch module.

Comment: Do you see added header in browser Network tab? Is key correct?

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'url_here' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Yes the key is correct, again it worked with the JS fetch module.

Comment: Then you're going to need to read about CORS, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: CORS has very little to do with whether the "key" you cite here is correctly passed.

Comment: Yes I am familiar with CORs and know this is not a CORs issue. The api key itself works and is implemented in other code. I know I am doing something wrong in the code above but am unclear as to what. If anyone know the help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Today, I ran into the EXACT same issue.
After checking the network tab in the dev console of Chrome (hit F12),
I found an interesting preflight response:

[image]

Here, the `access-control-allow-headers` deliver the answer to the problem. They simply don't allow `X-API-Key`, but instead I was able to use `access-token` and then it worked... at least I didn't get a CORS error anymore.
In my case, the api docs were just 'buggy'.

hth

Comment: just to clarify. This didn't solve the underlying issue of a mssing `X-API-Key` field on the `access-control-allow-headers`. Had to contact the developers of the providing servers and report this as a bug.